# create a symbolic link to multiple directory centos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, symlink

I have currently created a symbolic link in var/www/html/lenova/ . It is currently linked to "assets"
when I execute

```
   ll
```

this is what gets displayed

```
    assets -> ../../../assets
```

I need to create another link to assets in a different folder var/www/html/dell.

so end results would be

```
   assets-> ../../../assets
```

when I execute

```
  ln -s assets ../../../assets
```

it displays

```
 ln: creating symbolic link `../../../assets/assets` to `assets`: File exists
```

How can I achieve the second symbolic link as-well?
This folder needs to be shared by multiple projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Biffen stated, the arguments to `ln` are target first, then the link name. `man ln` shows:

```
SYNOPSIS
       ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
       ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

Assuming that 'var/www/html/dell' (the directory where you want the link) is the current working directory, you don't even need to specify the link name as you want it to be the same as the target: `ln -s ../../../assets`  Although, personally I am in the habit of specifying the destination directory: `ln -s ../../../assets .`  If you really wanted to have the arguments in the order which you were using, you could use the `-t` option: `ln -s -t . ../../../assets` However, in that case you are specifying a directory, not the name of the link.  To force the specifying the name of the link instead of a directory, use the `-T` option.

If you are not sure how a command works both the `man`, and `info` commands are available to provide information. It is not uncommon to use either an additional command window to show the man/help information while you are working, or to use job control to have the information available in the same command instance.